# Mysql Stored procedure returns result set size of zero when called from Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a stored procedure written in Mysql using Common table expression(CTE) "WITH" clause. That stored procedure returns valid rows when invoked through Mysql workbench but returns zero rows when called from Hibernate. Here is the stored procedure code.

Mysql version used: 8.0.16 MySQL Community Server
Hibernate version used is 5.0

```
CREATE DEFINER=`sa`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `spXXXXXXXXXX`(
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    IN testparam longtext,
    IN testCode varchar(20)
)
BEGIN

    -- format testparam '`a,b,c`' as ('a','b','c')
    if(testparam is NOT NULL AND testparam != '') then
        set testparam = REPLACE(testparam,', ',',');
        set testparam = REPLACE(testparam,'`','(''');
        set testparam = REPLACE(testparam,'`',''')');
        set testparam = REPLACE(testparam,',',''',''');
    end if;


    set @sqlQuery = concat('With CTE_Test as(select a.*,row_number() over (order by Last_Modified_Date desc )
                as row_num from XXXXXX a
                where XXXXX_Code in 
                (select XXXXX_Code FROM XXXXXXX where XXXXXXX in
                (select xxxxxx from testtbl where xxxxxxxx in (''',testparam,''')
                and active = 1 and Company_Code = ''',testCode,''')) 
                and a.active = 1 and a.Company_Code = ''',testCode,''')');

    set @sqlQuery = concat(@sqlQuery, ' select * from CTE_Test ');

     prepare query from @sqlQuery;
     EXECUTE query;
     deallocate prepare query;
END
```

Java code:

```
Query storedProcedure = em.createNamedQuery("spXXXXXXXXX");
    storedProcedure.setParameter("testparam", testparam != null ? testparam.toString() : null);
    storedProcedure.setParameter("testCode", testCode);
    List<SpResponse> SectionList = (ArrayList<SpResponse>) storedProcedure.getResultList();
    logger.info("Result-->" + SectionList.size());
```

Comment: Do you have OUT parameter in the stored procedure?.I am not able to see any in the stored procedure definition.If yes,then show us the java code which you are calling.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No i don't have OUT parameter in stored procedure to write the result to. I thought execute of prepared statement returns the result of the select statement. I added my java code too in the question.

Comment: you have one less 'X' in your javacode for the procedure name ?